# Как сделать ползунковый ProgressBar ели я не знаю его max значения ? (сколько конкретно строк будет в listview)

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView lv;
    public Elements content;
    public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
        new NewThread().execute();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.pro_item, titleList);
        }

   public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://").maxBodySize(0).get();
                content = doc.select("tr");

                titleList.clear();

                for (Element contents : content) {
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                    publishProgress(progress);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}}}
```

Comment: 1 не понятно что вам нужно.  2 код из 2006 года?

Comment: Да как? Просто после того как обновите значение в ListView, берите количество строк и пихайте это значение в верхню границу прогресс бара. Самое удобно было бы это делать в самом адаптере, когда вы перерисовываете список.